# Difference between COUNT(ColName) vs COUNT(ALL(ColName))

Tags: sql-server

Both query return the same output:

```
select COUNT(id) from Employee

select COUNT(All(id)) from Employee
```

So what is the difference in SQL-Server 2008R2?

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference.  `ALL` is the default keyword, as opposed to `DISTINCT`.